# How to use Sublime Text "ImportHelper" to remove unused imports

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime and "[ImportHelper](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ImportHelper)", and my OS is Linux, and my Sublime version is 3.

I read in the documentation that there's a way to removed unused imports pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

I tried this but it doesn't work. The unused imports are not removed from the .ts file. How can I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ImportHelper), the keyboard shortcut to remove unused imports is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. That means you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, release, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. The command should also be available from the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).